# A list on which there are duplicates(on sequence),a part of which is needed to be transferred

Tags: list, duplicates, prolog

This question is about a type of custom "cryptography" on which a word has duplicate letters in sequence. After the duplicate follows a part that is misplaced and needs to end up at the back of the list. My rule has the structure as: crypto(Word1,Word2) where the Word1 is a crypto and Word2 is uncrypted/answer

> changed some code as i found something closer to the answer

What do i want :

```
?- crypto([h,a,a,o,m,e,n,n,d,s], L).  
L = [h,a,n,d,s,o,m,e]
```

What do i get if(1 duplicate) :

```
?- crypto([h,a,a,o,m,e,n,d,s], L).  
L = [h,a,n,d,s,o,m,e]
```

I tried the following code:

```
crypto([],[]).
crypto([H|T], List) :-   %is true when its duplicate 
     member(H, T),
     append(Empty_at_first,[Arxh|Telos],[H|T]), 
     append(A,[Ar|Te],Telos),
     ml(Te,3,Result_ml), 
     append([H],Result_ml,Result),
     crypto(Result,List).
crypto([H| T], [H|T1]) :- 
      not(member(H, T)),                     
      crypto(T, T1).

ml([H|T],R):-append(T,[H|[]],R).
ml(A,0,A).

ml([H|T],N,R):-
   N1 is N - 1, ml([H|T],R1), ml(R1,N1,R),!.
```

Comment: thanks for the grammar/spelling corrections @Jason Aller

Comment: What is your question? What part doesn't work how you would like it to work?

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie i have find spare parts of the code i need but i struggle to fusion them also i dont know if it is the right approach.In summary (A word has duplicates followed by a part which is missplaced).My approach was to remove the duplicate which are not part of the answer and then try to forge a list using some kind of append such as the part that is missplaced end up at the front of the list so i can use move_to_last.I do believe there is some easiest way but i cant figure it out.This code i provided doesnt work as inteded because i cant move the part that is missplaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification is less clear than it should be, but here is my understanding: An encrypted sequence consists of the following, in order:

- some prefix
- a duplicated delimiter indicating the start of the displaced sequence
- the displaced "final" sequence itself
- a duplicated delimiter indicating the end of the displaced sequence
- a suffix

A decrypted sequence has the same parts in a different order:

- the prefix
- the "start" delimiter (only once)
- the "end" delimiter (only once)
- the suffix
- the "final" part

A useful strategy to solve this problem is to write separate predicates for identifying the parts of an encrypted sequence, and for putting those parts back together to get a decrypted sequence. Generally, in Prolog (even more than in other programming languages) you should try hard to recognize distinct sub-problems and write separate predicates for dealing with them.

For example:

```
encrypted_parts(Encrypted, Prefix, X, Y, Suffix, Final) :-
    append(Prefix, L1, Encrypted),
    L1 = [X, X | L2],
    append(Final, L3, L2),
    L3 = [Y, Y | L4],
    Suffix = L4.
```

This behaves like this:

```
?- encrypted_parts([h,a,a,o,m,e,n,n,d,s], Prefix, X, Y, Suffix, Final).
Prefix = [h],
X = a,
Y = n,
Suffix = [d, s],
Final = [o, m, e] ;
false.
```

It recognizes that `a` and `n` are the duplicated delimiters and that `[o, m, e]` is the sequence in between, which should end up at the end of the decrypted sequence.

Putting these parts back together is very similar:

```
decrypted_parts(Decrypted, Prefix, X, Y, Suffix, Final) :-
    append(Prefix, L1, Decrypted),
    L1 = [X, Y | L2],
    append(Suffix, L3, L2),
    Final = L3.
```

And finally:

```
crypto(Encrypted, Decrypted) :-
    encrypted_parts(Encrypted, Prefix, X, Y, Suffix, Final),
    decrypted_parts(Decrypted, Prefix, X, Y, Suffix, Final).

?- crypto([h,a,a,o,m,e,n,n,d,s], Decrypted).
Decrypted = [h, a, n, d, s, o, m, e] ;
false.
```

All of this is more readable with DCGs, if you know about them already:

```
encrypted(Prefix, X, Y, Suffix, Final) -->
    list(Prefix),
    list([X, X]),
    list(Final),
    list([Y, Y]),
    list(Suffix).

decrypted(Prefix, X, Y, Suffix, Final) -->
    list(Prefix),
    [X],
    [Y],
    list(Suffix),
    list(Final).

list([]) -->
    [].
list([X | Xs]) -->
    [X],
    list(Xs).

crypto_dcg(Encrypted, Decrypted) :-
    phrase(encrypted(Prefix, X, Y, Suffix, Final), Encrypted),
    phrase(decrypted(Prefix, X, Y, Suffix, Final), Decrypted).
```

Comment: Thanks @Isabelle Newbie you absolute legend works like a charm

Comment: Is `list//1` really an appropriate name? Say, `phrase(( list(Xs), list(Ys) ), Zs)` is not about two lists, but one, `Zs`.

Comment: I'd say that that goal is about a relation between three lists. But I'm open to concrete suggestions for improvement.